# How to count the number of userInteractionDisabled rows in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a tableview with dynamic rows. On certain conditions,I am reloading the data in didSelect and didDeSelect methods and I am making the cell with userInteractionEnable as false. How to calculate the total no.of.disabled(grayed out) cells at the end? Please help.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  If the answer helps, [it's customary to accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), to mark the question as answered. It benefits you, us, and other users who visit the question!

Comment: Thank you so much PetahChristian. It worked. Apologise for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't, according to the way you are trying to store that detail, as cells are reused, and I am guessing there are more rows than visible cells.

What you need to do is update a disabled/enabled flag in the indexPath for the model, and then get a count from that model data.

**Update:**

Each row would have its own flag.  You'd store these flags in an array in the model.

I assume that the rows are initially enabled, so you would make sure that your model sets each row's `isDisabled` flag to NO.

What you want to track is the number of disabled rows.

Somewhere in your code, perhaps in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you are checking the row's condition, and, depending on that condition, setting its `isDisabled` flag.

```
    modelData[indexPath.row].disabled = YES;
```

When you need to get the count of disabled rows, you iterate through the model and add up the number of rows that are disabled:

```
NSUInteger numberOfDisabledRows = 0;
for (SomeModelClass *row in modelData) {
    if ([row isDisabled]) {
        numberOfDisabledRows++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%ld disabled rows", (long)numberOfDisabledRows);
```

Comment: I have tried Enabling/disabling flag. My problem now is, more than one cell may grey out based on the condition. In that case, no.of.disabled cells count is not proper. For example, I have 5 rows. Based on the condition, 2 rows are selected, 1 is unselected and 2 are disabled(at the same time). How will I count now? Please help.

Comment: The rows which are disabled would have their disabled flag set.  To count them, you iterate (fast enumerate) through the model, adding up the number of rows which have their disabled flag set.  In your example, you should get a total of 2 (disabled) rows.  I added code to illustrate how to do this.